# Trying to retrieve Facebook news feed

Tags: php, facebook

I have a script that should retrieve the last 5 posts from my Facebook news feed and display them. However it's not outputting anything. I've created an app but is there something I'm missing?

```
<?php

require 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => '*********',
    'secret' => '****************************',
));



$fbApiGetPosts = $facebook->api('/*****************/feed?limit=5');
if (isset($fbApiGetPosts["data"]) && !empty($fbApiGetPosts["data"])) {

    foreach($fbApiGetPosts["data"] as $dPost){

        if($dPost["from"]["id"]==$fbid){
             $dTime = strtotime($dPost["created_time"]);

            $myTime=date("M d Y h:ia",$dTime);
            ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo($dPost["link"]); ?>">
                                        <?php echo($dPost["message"]) . "<br>" .
                                         $myTime; ?></a></li>
            <?php
        }
    }   
}


?>
```

Thanks,

Fraser

Comment: You can only get your own posts

Comment: did you authorize the app already, with facebook login?

Comment: I know I can only get my own posts - how would I authorize the app?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking